# Excel: Pivot table not showing all Fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My Pivot table is not showing all the fields. I have some data that someone SQL-ed. I add two more columns to the data using Excel formulas. When I select the entire data and click on insert Pivot Table, the Table/Range says : `"Table_Query_from_ACTSQLServer"`

Now, at this point I have said `"OK"` or manually selected the range to include the two new columns that I created but in either case the Pivot Table (in the new sheet) does not contain the two new rows that I created.

An additional piece of pertinent information might be that the workbook already contains Pivot Tables I made yesterday from the same data but that was before I had added the two new columns. I hope to be able to use the new columns to update all the earlier pivot tables, if only they show up on the field list. Please help!!

Comment: @pnuts I have used that also, but I meant initially when you click on "Pivot Table" a window pops up asking you the range and where to place it, there I typed the Range instead of the "Table_Query....Server"

Comment: Pivot tables can be picky about their data source - you're better off just copy and pasting the data as values - replacing the old data. - or even try pasting it into a different workbook. That will get rid of any weird formatting or references that could be causing problems.

Comment: @Stephan1010 would copy and paste preserve the "live" automatic update? The idea is that next month's data will be SQLd by simply changing the date field and then hopefully the Pivot Charts will update automatically as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question was asked and answered over on answers.microsoft.com [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/new-data-columns-do-not-show-as-pivot-table-fields/5232406e-1e08-4760-80f2-72fa65485463?page=1).

The best answer seemed to be to use an Excel *Table* as the data source range of the pivot instead of just cell ranges.

> Shane Devenshire replied on  January 22, 2011
>   Reply In reply to MacG31 post on January 21, 2011
>   Hi,
>   In 2007 you can solve this problem very simple by
>   1. defining the source data as a Table (Insert, Table).
>   2.  Creating a new pivot table,
>   3. Adding a new field to the column adjacent to the right side of the Table (not the pivot table),
>   4. Refreshing.

You may also be a victim of the Pivot Cache not being updated. Try clearing the old items/fields and refreshing each pivot table in your workbook. You can take a look at the walk-through that I used [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot04.html)
or [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/04/22/clear-old-items-in-pivot-table-drop-downs/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for linking to those solutions. I'm sorry I have fallen behind in thanking you and accepting your answer. I will try those solutions suggested and give an update comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just had almost an identical problem except initial data was not created from SQL query.

Simply walking through and refreshing all existing pivot tables in the workbook that used the data that I had added columns to, and then refreshing the new pivot table I wanted the new columns to appear as a pivot table field in, worked.

To refresh pivot table, right click in table and click refresh.

Answer (score 0):

when the dialog asked for the table I inserted the actual range of the table with the added columns (for example A1:bq1206)instead of the default "table 1"